# When should I downvote an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I was reviewing a question yesterday, and I found two answers. One had the appropriate answer, but only in one sentence, and the other one was a good-quality answer, it contained code and an example link, but it was somewhat different than the actual question.

I got confused; what kind of answers should be down-voted?

Comment: When *"this answer is not useful"*; beyond that, as long as you're voting on the *content* not the *author*, it's up to you.

Comment: @Louis that seems to be about whether it's OK to *"downvote answers of off-topic questions"*

Comment: If an answer is not an answer, there is a flag for this by the way